# Get List of object mongodb driver net core

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi I need obtain a list of objects from mongodb, I'm using mongodb.driver and net core:

the error that i have is:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursor>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    ...\Implementations\EventRepository.cs  104 Active

how I can return a IEnumerable correctly, these is my code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> GetEventsByOwnerId(IDictionary<string, string> paramsEvents)
{
    try
    {
        FilterDefinition<Event> filter = Builders<Event>.Filter.Eq("OwnerId", paramsEvents["OwnerId"]);
        var response = await this.GetMongoCollection().FindAsync<Event>(filter);

        return response;
    }
    catch (MongoException e)
    {
        throw new MongoException(e.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FindAsync](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync__1_1.htm) method returns [IAsyncCursor](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursor_1.htm) which does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` so there's no implicit cast that can be run here. You have to use `.ToList()` to "materialize" the query (fetch the data):

```
var response = await this.GetMongoCollection().FindAsync<Event>(filter);
return response.ToList();
```